# How to implement ScrollTricks with a gridView

Tags: android, android-layout, google-plus

I need to make something like the google+ profile header (a background image that hides when scroll up and a fixed header on top), but i don't have idea how to do it with a gridview.

I looked into the scrolltricks example from [Roman Nurik](http://code.google.com/p/romannurik-code/)  and he did it on StickyFragment, my problem is that I need to use a gridview to recycle the views.

Attached some images to be more clear.

[image: Expanded Google+ Profile Header]

[image: Google+ Profile Header Scrolling]

[image: Google+ Profile Header hidden and fixed header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find this solution:
http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/10/04/making-that-google-plus-profile-screen/

maybe it can help you.